# SharePoint 2013 workflow, changes made in designer are not getting reflected.

Tags: designer-workflow

I have a published a SharePoint 2013 workflow from designer and it is working fine. Now I made a change to it and published from designer. But the changes are not reflecting in SharePoint site when I create new requests.

I tried clearing the cache in designer (as suggested by many forums) But it didn't help me. However when I delete the workflow and publish as a new workflow then it is working fine (well obviously).

Question: Is there any proper solution or work around for the current situation? As all the existing requests will loose its instances if I delete and add the workflow again and again.

Thanks,
Vetri